# fetchmail without an mda

Tags: fetchmail

I would like to retrieve mail from a server using fetchmail and have it deposit it directly into an mailbox/repository and not hand it off to a mda.
Is this possible? How?

In the alternate, is there an mda which simply recieves things from er fetchamil and stores them in some sort of repository without doing any processing?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`mda` option in your `.fetchmailrc`](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/fetchmail-man.html#9) to specify [maildrop](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/) or [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/) as your MDA.

```
mda "/usr/bin/maildrop"
```

This will deposit the mail in the system mailbox (typically `/var/spool/mail/handygandy` or `/var/mail/handygandy`). If you want it elsewhere, or if you want to dispatch the mails based on their content, write a [`~/.mailfilter`](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/maildropfilter.html) [file](http://www.courier-mta.org/maildrop/maildropex.html).

```
to mail/fetched
```

Comment: haha yeah I agree this probably does what the OP wants, but it's not "fetchmail without an mda" lol

Answer (score 3):

Since mda is just a program read the whole email from stdin and write it to somewhere, you can write the simplest mda in bash:

```
mda "/bin/sh -c 'cat > INBOX/new/$(date +%''s_%N)'"
```

The tricky single quote is a work-around to avoid "%s", because fetchmail will replace "%s" with the current user name: [Encode literal percent in fetchmail's mda option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195188/encode-literal-percent-in-fetchmails-mda-option)

Comment: I just tried it with only `cat` and it worked as well: `cat >> somefile`. I guess that means `/bin/sh` is optional.